# SocketIO message originated from the server is not working

Tags: javascript, python, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am developing an app and using the `websockets` for the server-client communication. The concept is to have the client requesting from the server for messages and a few times the server needs to push some messages to the client (without the latter has requested for them). (I'll use front-end and back-end to describe my app)

The app works when the front-end requests from the back-end but it doesn't for the case where the back-end needs to be the originator of the message (i.e. emit data without the front-end has requested for that). In that case the websocket seems to stall and blocked for a few seconds, until the client disconnects (reason timeout) and connects again. Of course, the topic sent by the back-end/server is never received by the client, i.e. the `/non_requested_topic` as seen below.

For the **BACK-END** I am using `flask-socketio` in PY2.7 and

**events_handling.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from flask import request
from emit_topics import emit_topic

def on_connect():
  print("Client {} connected".format(request.sid))
  # set the client ID to unrequested.py blah blah

def on_disconnect():
  print("Client {} disconnected".format(request.sid))

def on_topic_request(data):
  data_rx = "blah blah"
  to = request.sid # client
  namespace = "my_namespace"
  emit_topic(topic_name="/topic_name", data_rx, to, namespace)
```

**emit_topics.py**

```
def emit_topic(topic_name, data, to, namespace):
  socket_io.emit(topic_name, data=data, to=to, namespace=namespace)
```

And then there is a function that calls `emit_topic` and pushes some data to the client (without the client has requested for them):

**unrequested.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from emit_topics import emit_topic

def function_a(self):
  to =  self.client_id # client id that is set every time the client connects 
  namespace = "my_namespace"
  data_rx="Msg from the server"
  print("Check the client id {}".format(to)) # this matches with the one observed for the ws
  emit_topic (topic_name="/non_requested_topic", data_rx, to, namespace)
```

For the **FRONT-END**:
There is an `HTML` file where:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.5/socket.io.min.js"></script>

var socket = io("my_namespace", {'forceNew': true});
var interval_timer;

socket.on('connect', function() {
  console.log('Connected to the server');
  interval_timer = setInterval(topics_request, 5000);
});

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
  console.log('Disconnected from the server');
  clearInterval(interval_timer);
});

socket.on("/topic_name", (msg) => {
  console.log("/topic_name rx ", msg);
});

socket.on("/non_requested_topic", (msg) => {
  console.log("Non requested topic rx ", msg);
});

function topics_request(){
  socket.emit("topic_request", {"topic": "/topic_name"}) // some topic name
}
```

Is a request from the client required first to trigger the `/non_requested_topic` or is there a way for the client to keep listening to that?

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues with your code.

First of all, Python 2.7 has not been a supported version of Python for Flask-SocketIO for a while. I strong advise you to start using Python 3.

Your use of namespaces in the server is very inconsistent. Your connect and disconnect handlers do not use a namespace. Your `on_topic_request` function doesn't either. But then the `emit_topic` function accepts a namespace as an argument, which you set to `my_namespace`. Why do you use a namespace only when emitting but not when receiving events? Also, namespaces are supposed to start with a slash.

Comment: Unfortunately, the application and the framework that is based on is not compatible with python 3, thus I have to use py2  atm. I didnt post the original bits hence the inconsistency with the namespace and the missing `/`. To make Flask-SocketIO work with py2.7 I had to install `simplejson` and update the `client.py` in the `engineio` package. I am not sure whether this is the issue and the server can't send to the client without the latter has requested for it

Comment: It's hard for me to know, I haven't tested the code on Python 2.7 for a long time and I do not plan to make changes to make it compatible, sorry. You can look for an older release, back from when Python 2.7 was supported. The change log for python-socketio and python-engineio indicate which versions are the last to support Python 2.

Comment: No worries and thank you for the last commit. I downgraded the versions so I don't have to do the trick with the `simplejson`. However, the issue with the js client not being able to receive a topic, generated and published by the python server, still remains. A workaround is the js-client to specifically request for this every x secs, until PY3 is used.